# Скачивание файла средствами Html

Tags: php, html, download

Есть ссылка с URL на файл и атрибутом download. При попытке скачать файл выбивает "Ошибка сети".
Код ссылки выглядит так:

```
echo "<td><a  href='" . $r['link'] . "' download=''>Ссылка</a></td>";
```

Сами ссылки хранятся в таком виде:

```
C:\OSPanel\domains\dipl\web\upload\jxlrwtest.xls
```

Пробовал в мозиле, хроме и IE - в мозиле и хроме "Ошибка сети", в IE ничего не выводит и не скачивает файл. Помогите найти решение.

Comment: Возможно, файла по данной ссылке не существует. 

Мне кажется, что `C:\OSPanel\...` похоже на ссылку на какой-то локальный файл, лежащий не на сервере, а на компьютере.

Только что проверил Ваш код на рабочих ссылках - работает!

Comment: Ну ospanel - папка с open server. А дальше уже сам проект

Comment: Вам нужно указывать ссылку вида домен.ru/upload/jxlrwtest.xls
C:\OSPanel\... это локальный путь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Политика безопасности JS не позволяет Вам получить доступ к файлам на диске пользователя. То бишь не стоит использовать для работы с тегом `download` локальные ссылки.

Ваш код на внешних ссылках работает!

Выгрузите свой проект вместе с рабочими файлами на внешний хостинг, и скачивание файлов будет работать как надо!

Comment: Да, подправил ссылки и всё работает как нужно. Спасибо большое